# click inside body to remove class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got an accordion style menu, what I'm trying to do is to remove the `open` class when anywhere inside the body tag is clicked so it collapses. I've got the code but doesn't work, get the following error in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'hasClass'

Code:

```
var toggleMainNav = function ($mainNav) {
    var isOpen = $mainNav.hasClass('open');

    if (isOpen) {
        $('body').unbind('click');
        $mainNav.removeClass('open');
    } else {
        $('body').bind('click', toggleMainNav);
        $mainNav.addClass('open');
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to ensure that you are getting a jquery object and not just a dom element. `console.log($mainNav);` before you declare `isOpen` and ensure you have what you think you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using a DOM element while you want to use a jQuery object.

Wrap your variable in jQuery style :

```
$($mainNav).hasClass("open");
```

Comment: Ahh, works in Chrome and I.E, but not in Firefox, I get this error in Firebug: TypeError: $mainNav.addClass is not a function

Comment: Maybe I'm saying non-sense but the `$` of your variable could lead to error. Give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$("body").click(function(){
      $mainNav.toggleClass("open");
    });
```